# Where should I put the application.properties file when deploying an app in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am currently deploying a *.war* file on Apache Tomcat.

I have already finished setting up the database, and the *ROOT.war* file is already deployed on */opt/tomcat/webapps/*.

The *ROOT.war* file that I have been assigned to deploy also came with an *application.properties* file.

What I did was put the *application.properties* file on the root of the ROOT folder. Like this:

[image: ROOT.war location in Apache Tomcat]

Now, it's currently not running.
[image: ROOT not running]

And when I try to start it, the Tomcat Web Application Manager throws this error:

> FAIL - Application at context path / could not be started FAIL -
>   Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

What I did next was check the logs located in /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out

This one line made me hunch that the problem is that the location of my *application.properties* file.

> 2020-03-06 11:42:15.978  WARN 4219 --- [io-8080-exec-27]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to parse configuration class [asia.edusuite.sample.Application];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not
>   resolve placeholder 'property.location' in value
>   "file:${property.location}/application.properties"

Where do you think I should put the *application.properties* file?

Thank you very much!
-JeremyC

Comment: I think it has to be in `/WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: I tried putting it inside `WEB-INF/classes` but no luck for me, it didn't work. I still get the `Could not resolve placeholder 'property.location' in value "file:${property.location}/application.properties"` error. Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe it's the `@PropertySource` annotation that is not correctly used. The value printed in the ouput seems weird to me. I'm more familiar with `@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })` or `@PropertySource(value={"file:application.properties"})`. I'm not sure you can define a custom location for your application.properties using this kind of logic. As you try to resolve the path of your application.properties, you probably can't resolve it trying to read the location in the application.properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'm afraid I don't have the source file for the Java application. I was just tasked to deploy it to run on Apache Tomcat. Again, thanks a lot mate!

Comment: In this case, if it's not a new application and it has been deployed in the past, I'm probably wrong. If this has never been deployed, you should show the error output to the developers! No problem, hope it helped you!

Comment: This has been deployed before, the developer told me that he just dumped the configuration files and the ROOT.war from their development server. I will update the thread once I solve the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The locations Spring will look for application.properties are defined [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Files in WEB-INF/classes are in the root classpath and should be discoverable unless your code is specifically looking somewhere else.  If you don't have the source, why not decompile the class to see what's going on?  (There are lots of them out there including one that comes with Intellij - you can just open the .class file.)